# How to include the word "page" in \pageref{} command output

Tags: cross-referencing

How can i get automatically the output "page X" and not only "X", when using the `\pageref{}` command?

Comment: `\let\pagereforig\pageref  \renewcommand{\pageref}[1]{page \pagereforig{#1}}` ... if really necessary or use `cleveref` and the `\cpageref` or `\Cpageref` commands (depending on uppercase/lowercase if you need this)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer This is something I'll never understand: Why on earth do you put your answer into a comment field?

Answer (score 2):

Without any further package, using a redefinition of `\pageref` (and storing the old definition before) is perhaps the best approach, more sophisticated approachs will apply `cleveref` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\let\latexpageref\pageref

\newcommand{\pagename}{Page}

\renewcommand{\pageref}[1]{%
  \pagename\ \latexpageref{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

See \pageref{foo} or \pageref{foobar} for more information. 

\section{Foo}\label{foo}
\blindtext[10]

\section{Foobar}\label{foobar}
\end{document}
```